# Optimizing location updates when adding a new object

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core

I'm trying to keep a bunch of Objects called `Machine` in their proper order. I was wondering if it'd be possible to further optimize the function `HandleLocationCount` for performance.

Any general feedback is of course also welcome. The function `HandleLocationCount` is only executed when a new `Machine` object is added.

The `Machine` object is below, it references a `Section` object, which acts as a container for the various machines.

```
public class Machine
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string OrderNo { get; set; }

    public Section Section { get; set; }

    public int LocationInSection { get; set; }

    public ForcedLocation ForcedLocation { get; set; } = ForcedLocation.Blank;
}
```

Section object & enum for completeness; it's an enum instead of a boolean for future proofing:

```
public class Section
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string OrderNo { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Machine> MachinesInSection { get; set; }
}

public enum ForcedLocation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Does nothing for the location.
    /// </summary>
    Blank,

    /// <summary>
    /// This entity is always last in the location.
    /// </summary>
    Keep_Last,
}
```

The function that calls the `HandleLocationCount` function looks like this; a user is able to manually set the location if needed.

```
    public Machine Add(Machine entity)
    {
        if (entity.LocationInSection == 0)
        {
            IEnumerable<Machine> AmountMachines = GetMachinesByOrderNoAndSection(entity.OrderNo, entity.Section);
            entity.LocationInSection = handleLocationCount(AmountMachines);
        }

        _machineRepository.Add(entity);

        return entity;
    }
```

The function that returns the index just searches every machine for their order number & name, the repository itself is just an interface that has a generic index function

```
public IEnumerable<Machine> GetMachinesByOrderNoAndSection(string orderno, Section section)
    {
        return _machineRepository.Index()
         .Where(m => m.OrderNo == orderno && m.Section == section);
    }
```

And the code for the location looks like this, it updates older machines if this is needed; else just passes the new location for the machine

```
    private int HandleLocationCount(IEnumerable<Machine> AmountOfMachines)
    {
        int newLocation = AmountOfMachines.Count() + 1;

        foreach (var Machine in AmountOfMachines)
        {
            int oldLocation = Machine.LocationInSection;
            switch (Machine.ForcedLocation)
            {
                case ForcedLocation.Blank:
                    break;
                case ForcedLocation.Keep_Last:
                    Machine.LocationInSection = AmountOfMachines.Count() + 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (Machine.LocationInSection != oldLocation)
            {
                newLocation = oldLocation;
                Update(Machine);
            }
        }

        return newLocation;
    }
```

Comment: How many `machine`'s can be there with `ForcedLocation == ForcedLocation.Keep_Last` ?

Comment: There can be max one per section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `GetMachinesByOrderNoAndSection` returns an `IEnumerable<Machine>`. Depending on how the method is implemented, iterating the enumeration may query the database. In `HandleLocationCount` you are iterating it and also calling `.Count()` on it several times. The LINQ `Count` extension method might also iterate the enumeration.

Make sure to iterate it only once, e.g. by working on a list crated with `var list = AmountOfMachines.ToList();`, if something like this is not already done in `GetMachinesByOrderNoAndSection`.

Also, you could use two distinct variables for storing `newLocation` and `AmountOfMachines.Count() + 1` and call the latter only once.

---

I am not sure to understand the logic right. But you seem to assign the same `AmountOfMachines.Count() + 1` to all the `Keep_Last` machines. If this is the case, you could simply assign them a constant number like `Int32.MaxValue`. They would be kept last once and for all.

Another possible approach is to partition the number range into two ranges:

1. `[1 .. Int32.MaxValue / 2]` for `Blank`.
2. `[Int32.MaxValue / 2 + 1 .. Int32.MaxValue]` for `Keep_Last`.

Adavantages:

- The machines stay in their respective group.
- They are ordered.
- Adding a machine at the end of a group does not require the `LocationInSection` of others to be updated.

Instead of getting the count, you would get the maximium value in the two groups.

```cs
int nextBlank = machineList
    .Where(m => m.ForcedLocation == ForcedLocation.Blank)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
    .Max() + 1;
int nextKeepLast = machineList
    .Where(m => m.ForcedLocation == ForcedLocation.Keep_Last)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(Int32.MaxValue / 2)
    .Max() + 1;
```

Comment: I will add the `GetMachinesByOrderNoAndSection` function to my question, would it be better to cast it to a list right away when querying the database for this?

Comment: Additionally, the Location number is used later in the program to get the next or previous machine if it's needed for calculations. I will try the MaxValue, but I do believe that'd cause issues

Comment: The `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` perform a lazy evaluation. This can prevent loading a lot of data into memory at once. Lazy evaluation gets the records being iterated just in time. But since you must get the count and perform a foreach, both iterating, you need a list. So, it depends on the number of machines. Just a few dozen? No problem with returning a list. 10s or 100s of thousands? Not ideal. If the number is really huge making 2 queries would be better. One query just getting the `COUNT(*)` returning only one record and another one returning all the machines in a `IEnumerable<>`.

Comment: The expected amount of machines per order number is somewhere between 20-50, however for the entire solution  I'm probably looking at a few thousand machines. Would it be recommended to split the queries? I thought I'd be better to just use one query for getting everything and only then splitting things.

Comment: Since this methods returns always only one order and one section, have it return a `List<Machine>`. You can then get the number of machines through the `list.Count` property (note, not `.Count()`!). Splitting the query is then superfluous.